# PassportJS Facebook Strategy - Ambiguous Error on OAuth

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am stuck trying to get basic OAuth flow for a login for my site. The clientID, secret, and callback URI all work but it only begins to fail when I do my second passport.authenticate for exchanging the token.

```
Error
    at C:\Users\denze\Desktop\personalSite\node_modules\passport-facebook\lib\strategy.js:165:21
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\denze\Desktop\personalSite\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\denze\Desktop\personalSite\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const passport = require('passport')
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy


passport.use(
    new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: someId,
        clientSecret: someSecret,
        callbackURL: 'https://289abc65.ngrok.io/auth/redirect',
        profileFields: ['email']
    },  function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        // asynchronous
        process.nextTick(function() {
        })
        console.log(profile)
    })
);

router.get('/login',passport.authenticate('facebook', 
    { scope : ['email']
}))


router.get('/redirect',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            successRedirect : '/',
            failureRedirect : '/'
        }));


module.exports = router;
```

! https://imgur.com/a/RApy8xq  Facebook API Settings

Comment: That only says _where_ the error occurred, but not what it actually _was._ So I would suggest you go read up on how to get the actual error message the API returned with your library first of all.

Comment: @CBroe I tried to go into the Strategy.js file to figure out the error but still could not understand what the message could be. Any ideas where to look? Genuinely asking